Vacua in holography?
I was reading some papers* on celestial holography which aims to apply the holographic principle to a flat spacetime, making a duality between a celestial sphere and a celestial conformal field theory (CCFT)
In these papers, the authors talk about CCFT vacua.
Are they referring to different vacua as in the string landscape? Does it mean that there could be different vacua with different CCFTs (similar to the vacua of the string theory landscape) existing in different celestial spheres?
*the papers:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.12469
https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.00606
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10935

you might benefit from reproducing an exact paragraph or section from each paper. Experienced physics folks probably would be able to grok a lot from that without having to dig through the entire papers. Here's an example of myself in your shoes asking about a paper in cryptography

It has nothing to do with the string landscape. Celestial holography does not yet have any string theory interpretation. It is an entirely bottom up approach to flat holography.
What the papers are referring to is the fact that asymptotically flat spacetimes have an infinite-dimensional asymptotic symmetry group known as the BMS group (unlike AdS). This then implies the existence of an infinite-dimensional vacuum Hilbert space. You can check out Strominger's lecture notes on the subject to understand this.

Thank you. What do you exactly mean when you say that it does not have any string theory interpretation? Isn't celestial holography compatible with string theory models?

@vengaq - It is not derived from string theory like AdS/CFT is. It is compatible with string theory. We just don't know what precise construction in string theory is needed to derive celestial holography.

Okay. On a related topic, I did a question to Andrew Strominger, namely: "Since in your paper you say that celestial amplitudes can be used to study UV complete theories, and therefore, to study possible consistent theories of quantum gravity, does it mean that we can use them to study every possible UV completion theory? All possible GUTs and all possible theories of quantum gravity? Could we use it to study every possible theory of everything like string theory, M-theory, loop quantum gravity, asymptotically safe quantum gravity...?". His answer was basically a "yes" @Prahar

This is consistent with Laurent Freidel and collaborators' works on corner symmetries and local holography (arxiv.org/abs/2212.12469 , arxiv.org/abs/2302.12799 & arxiv.org/abs/2407.11132) which are related to celestial holography, where I asked Luca Ciambelli if all possible models of quantum gravity could be applied to their models, and he again basically answered that yes, they could. @Prahar

Then, this makes me wonder: Is it possible that different CCFTs corresponding to these different fundamental theories of quantum gravity could exist in different celestial spheres? Or something similar to this? Or is it forbidden? (I've changed the original comment a bit trying to be more clear) @Prahar

I don't understand this point. There is one celestial sphere. What do you mean by different celestial spheres?

When I mentioned "multiple" celestial spheres I was thinking that perhaps in eternal inflation there could be different "pocket universes" or "baby universes" described by their own asymptotically flat spacetimes (therefore each one with their own celestial sphere). Or perhaps if we have a landscape of different vacua, or branes (as it happens in different string theories) where each one would have their own spacetime, and thus their own celestial sphere. Or this is a wrong picture? @Prahar
